# static library doesn't contain macro

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros, static-libraries, lib

I have a static library project (written in C language) and another sample project (written in C language) under Visual Studio 2015. I can use the *functions* located at the library in the sample project without any problem. My problem is that I have a macro in one of the header files in the static library project and I can't see (or use) this macro in the sample project. I receive this error: "unresolved external symbol ADD1 referenced in function main". How can I use this macro in the sample project?

Note: I use the library file in the sample project thanks to this pragma this pragma: #pragma comment(lib, "mylib.lib")

Comment: and how are you including the header file for the library?

Comment: Did you included headers in your code?

Comment: No, I do not! Moreover, I do not want to include any of the header files of the static library project. They are not supposed to be seen by other projects.

Comment: Well, so how do you think preprocessor can see those macro??...

Comment: I don't know. That was my question in fact. Should I define this macro as a function so that I can see in other project? What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: it's expected that a library has one header that other code includes that contains prototypes of the public functions - it's where you'd put the macro

Comment: If you want to hide your implementation, you must use functions, not macros. BTW you must have an header file that define prototypes of lib functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include your header with the `#include` directive, not with some pragma.

A header should be written so that it is the public interface to your library, even if the library code itself may not be open. Either the macro is public and can then be declared in the header, or it is not public in which case you should encapsulate it inside the library.

If the library code is pre-compiled and delivered as a binary, either declare it in a C file or in a H file that the caller does not have access to.

Comment: That `pragma` is for Visual Studio - it's a method to link the library's binary to the application. (`gcc` uses the `-l` option for this purpose).

Comment: @Attie The library is not a header, but it needs to provide one.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want to include any of the header files of the static library project. They are not supposed to be seen by other projects.

I think there is some confusion.

---

To make use of any library, you must know about its functions, datatypes (e.g: `enum`, `struct`, `typedef`), macros, etc... This all comes together to form the library's 'API'.

*Most* libraries (not all) will have some internal headers. You are correct, these are not supposed to be seen by other projects, and will be used strictly internally.

*All* libraries will have some 'public' headers that define their API. A code base Without a public API is either useless, or actually an application that stands on its own.